# command not found: shopt ON WSL Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, bashrc

I inserted couple of env. variables such as:

```
export WOS_MONGODB_URI='mongodb://localhost:27017/...'
export WOS_AWS_REGION='us-east-2'
export WOS_AWS_ENV='dev23'
export WOS_SEED_MODE='test'
export WOS_REDIS_READ_URI="redis://localhost:6379"
export WOS_REDIS_WRITE_URI="redis://localhost:6379"
export WOS_CACHE_PERIOD_SECONDS='300'
export MONGOOSE_MAX_POOL_SIZE='4'
```

into .bashrc file using `nano ~/.bashrc` command and after saving it and exited from .bashrc when I check I those varialbes using `echo $WOS_MONGODB_URI` bash terminal didn't respond. But when I opened .bashrc file using vscode it shows all of those edits. Then I entered `source ~/.bashrc` it gives this error:

```
/home/damika/.bashrc:26: command not found: shopt
/home/damika/.bashrc:34: command not found: shopt
/home/damika/.bashrc:121: command not found: shopt
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:45: command not found: shopt
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1596: parse error near `|'
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$
```

This shopt command is used in 4 places in my .bashrc file. However wsl doesn't recognize. Since I thought there might be a misconfiguration or issue with my wsl2, I tried:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion
source ~/.bashrc
```

but it doesn't solve the issue :/

Comment: It looks like you are trying to source a **bash**rc file in a **zsh** shell

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this, I was using MobaXterm x-server and it's using the Zsh shell. In Zsh, the configuration file is typically named `.zshrc`. So, the changes might not take effect for the Zsh shell. Finally I changed `.zshrc` file.

> nano ~/.zshrc

add export commands. To apply the changes immediately,

> source ~/.zshrc

Then check env variables:

> echo $WOS_MONGODB_URI